# Dividir arquivo do EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma base em um excel com 1 milhao de emails nela, e preciso dividir em 4 arquivos de  250 mil emails cada, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso com alguma função do excel ? obrigada

Comment: você provavelmente já resolveu o problema, uma vez que não respondeu os comentários, talvez possamos marcar sua pergunta como resolvido?

Answer (score 3):

Se você ja sabe a quantidade total de células, basta fazer manualmente, vá direto até uma determinada linha (250.000) bastando escrever do lado superior esquerdo o numero da linha em questão e apertar enter.

[image: Excel]

Ou utilize filtros avançados.

[Neste link tem um exemplo utilizando filtro avançado](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)

Comment: Fazer manualmente, a quebra de 1 milhão de linhas não deve ser muito fácil, não é não?

Comment: @Math basta selecionar da linha 01até a linha 250.000 recortar os dados e colar em outra planilha, fara isso 04 vezes e gastara bem menos recursos do micro do que deixar esta tarefa para o Excel gerenciar gastando memória e processamento e travando, correndo o risco de corromper a planilha!

Comment: Ok, mas como "Ir para" a linha 250.000? Essa é a minha dúvida. Scroll do mouse? Page downs infinitos? Por isso que digo não ser muito fácil.

Comment: @Math a Luana não deixou claro se essa planilha ira crescer dinamicamente ou ela ja esta em seu limite máximo, se ja esta no limite máximo é simples, o Excel permite que você vá direto até uma determinada linha bastando escrever do lado superior esquerdo o numero da linha em questão e selecionar os dados e pronto. Mas se a planilha for crescer dinamicamente, ai é mais vantajoso utilizar o filtro avançado como proposto ou até mesmo um banco de dados simples como Access ou MySql.

Comment: "vá direto até uma determinada linha bastando escrever do lado superior esquerdo o numero da linha em questão" esse é o ponto que eu queria chegar!! Eu usei Excel a minha vida inteira e nunca tinha visto (prestado atenção) à essa caixa! E olha que eu procurei, antes de ver sua resposta. Se você puser isso como resposta eu voto a favor dela.

Comment: @Math alterei a resposta, acho que agora esta mais didático, esta funcionalidade do excel é muito util.

Comment: Se pusesse um print ficaria show, mas do jeito que está já me ensinou algo que eu não sabia. +1, já tá excelente

Comment: @Math você pediu, ai esta.

Comment: Para mim essa é a resposta correta. Parabéns, e bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Answer (score 1):

Creio que uma solução em `VBA` seria bem mais prática do que uma manual e cansativa, então fiz isso aqui, caso não tenha experiencia com `macro`, eu deixei o código bastante explicado:

A ideia é pegar a `coluna A` e dividir ela de acordo com a variável `divisor`. As planilhas são salvas na pasta default `Meus Documentos`. A unica preocupação é que por rapidez usei o método de aproximação mais simples que arrendonda sempre pra mais: [AsymArith](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196652/pt-br), caso queira outro método, é só procurar nesse artigo do link.

```
Sub Dividir_em_arquivos()
Dim ultimalinha As Integer, divisor As Integer
Dim resultado As Double
Dim nomeaba As String, nomearquivo As String, nomeaba_loop As String, nomearquivo_loop As String

'pega o nome da sheet e do arquivo que voce esta executando a macro
nomearquivo = ActiveWorkbook.Name
nomeaba = ActiveSheet.Name

'seleciona a ultima linha da COLUNA "A"
ultimalinha = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'------------- > coloque aqui divisor
divisor = 4

'calculo (SOMENTE NUMEROS PARES, usando o SymArith: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196652/pt-br)
resultado = ultimalinha / divisor
resultado_apro = Int(resultado * 1 + 0.5) / 1


'loop para criar as planilhas e selecionar as colunas para copia
For i = 0 To divisor - 1
    resultado_inicio = (resultado_apro * i) + 1
    resultado_fim = resultado_apro * (i + 1)


    'set nome na planilha do loop
    nomeaba_loop = "numero" & i

    'cria planilha
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = nomeaba_loop
        .SaveAs Filename:=nomeaba_loop
    End With

    'adiciona aba para colar as informações
    nomearquivo_loop = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Sheets.Add.Name = nomeaba_loop

    'seleciona a planilha fonte
    Windows(nomearquivo).Activate
    Sheets(nomeaba).Select

    'Copia as informações da planilha fonte
    Range("A" & resultado_inicio & ":A" & resultado_fim).Copy

    'seleciona a planilha do loop
    Windows(nomearquivo_loop).Activate
    Sheets(nomeaba_loop).Select

    'cola as informações
    Range("A1:A" & resultado_apro).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'seleciona novamente a planilha fonte para começar o loop
    Windows(nomearquivo).Activate
    Sheets(nomeaba).Select

Next i

End Sub
```